# Cannot install SQL Server management on Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

Trying to install ssms (tried version 2012, 2014 and 2016) on Windows server 2008 R2 with both SQL server 2008 and SQL server 2012 installed on it (using remote desktop). But get following errors:

1. Error on installing ssms 2016 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process(0x80070020).
2. Error on installing ssms 2014: Extraction failed, though the file works on Windows 10.
3. Error on installing ssms 2012 : File is corrupt, but again the file works fine on windows 10.

Is it because of any missing component on sql server 2012 ? Should I repair it or am I missing .NET or any other program ?

Comment: Are you downloading only SSMS... i.e. this isn't part of an installation package of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it is only SSMS as SQL Server 2012 was already installed. I think the problem was that I was installing a 64bit version of SSMS as Windows Server 2008R2 was 64bit SP1, but the person who had installed SQL Server had installed a 32 bit version so I managed to solve the problem by installing SSMS 2012 32bit Service Pack 1.